# How to share common code between projects, while updating this code - will update it in the projects which uses this common code?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a lot of common logic, models and helpers.
I would like to come with a solution which will allow the following:

1. Other projects to use this common code
2. I can update and refactor this code, and it will be updated in all the projects which use it (unlike nuggets when you should update the nugget in each "client" project).

I tried to read a lot regarding this issue but couldn't find anything which gives the 2 bullets above.

Comment: Move the common code in the class library (separate project) and reference it in the Other projects. Will it not solve your issue?

Comment: Hi, it won't solve my problem because whenever I'll refactor the common code, i will need to update the dll in all the projects which use this dll. I would like to implement the common code in a different repository (different visual studio solution).

Comment: You really don't need to update the '.dll' in all the projects which use this dll. Just build the common code project and that's it. Try please.

Comment: Ok so you are saying i need to reference the "common project" from other projects. can I do it from a separate solution? (which on a different repo)

Comment: Exactly. It will solve to your issue.

Comment: Hey, I would really like you to be more specific, because I did try this solution, but once I reference a dll, it won't change unless I'll change the reference. The reference won't change if I build the common code solution.

Comment: What service are you hosting your code on? It should be possible to have a common storage location, but to create a specific solution I would need to know what service to work with. Thanks.

Comment: @MaozHeiferman - You don't reference a DLL, you reference the common project - Visual Studio then takes care of it for you.